# Get laravel validation exception messages in single array

Tags: laravel, validation

I want all Laravel validation exception messages in a single array.
Currently, I'm getting below response:

```
{
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "errors": {
    "name": [
      "The name has already been taken."
    ],
    "title": [
      "The title has already been taken."
    ],

  }
}
```

I need it like below:

```
{
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "errors": [
    "The name has already been taken.",
    "The title has already been taken."
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to show all error message together in blade template?

Comment: Am I correct is assuming that this is a response to an ajax request?

Comment: Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
          'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
          'body'  => 'required',
        ]);
        if ( $validator->fails() ) {
            return response()->json([
              'message' => 'The given data was invalid.',
              'errors'  => $validator->errors()->all()
            ]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the error messages in a single array by using [all function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#working-with-error-messages)

```
$validator->errors()->all();
```